# Unable to set the sslVerify to false

Tags: git, cordova, github, cordova-plugins

Actually I'm trying to install an ngCordova plugin for SQLite. But its giving me the error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443  while accessing https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed. On doing some research, I came across the solution to set the sslVerify to false. I am not able to set the command git config http.sslVerify "false" using the command prompt. It is giving me the error: could not lock config file /.gitconfig: No such file or directory. I also tried doing it manually by editing the gitconfig file; but its not happening

Answer (score 58):

The error message you mentioned from trying to set a configuration is printed when you try to set a local git configuration when you're not in a git repo.  You'll need to either set a global (add `--global` flag) configuration or cd into an existing git repo to set it to just that repo.

Ideally you want to limit the scope of the `sslVerify "false"` configuration, but if you're trying to get the initial clone you may need to set it as a global setting (temporarily) using:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
```

With that set you should be able to clone the repo, at which point I'd recommend unsetting it as a global configuration and setting it in your newly-cloned repo:

```
git config --global --unset http.sslVerify
cd <your newly-cloned repo>
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```

To verify what your configurations are set to after you're done you can run:

```
git config --global --list
git config --local --list
```

Comment: There's no need to set it and unset it globally; do your clone more safely with a temporary setting for that command only: `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone ...`.